# Getting JSON data using Angular JS's $http service

Tags: angularjs

I need to get JSON data from a server with URL :

```
http://xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx:8084/inpulse/api/user/listall
```

Here's my angular code:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('Controller', function ($scope,$http)  {
    $scope.email="";
    $scope.password="";
    $scope.sample="";

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx/inpulse/api/user/listall',
    })
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        var ret = data;
        $scope.sample = JSON.stringify(ret);
    })
    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        alert(status);
        // something went wrong :(
    });
});
```

Now the same code worked when i used a JSON test URL like http://ip.jsontest.com/.
Its Definitely not a problem with the server because I tested it with a REST client and got a response. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Can you please `console.log(data)` in the error callback and tell us what is shows ?

Comment: Are you calling it from a page in the me domain ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be a **[CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)** configuration issue.
If you are trying to access the server from a page that is not in the same domain/origin, you'll get an error because the server is not configured to allow CORS.

The **[error reported](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/ywTS7/)** by Chrome looks like this:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx/inpulse/api/user/listall`. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.

<sub>Other than that the code seems to work just as expected.</sub>

Comment: You simply can't guess that from nothing :)

Comment: That just proves the code works as expected. CORS should be configured on the server-side, not on the client-side. @Aperçu: Yes, I can ! That's why they call it "guessing". And no, it's not a good practice, but it was too long to be a comment, it is simple to verify and if it turns out not to be a problem, it can always be deleted :)

Comment: Yeah I understand your point, I was just waiting for OP to add more info about his problem to write down an answer

Comment: @Aperçu: Yeah, me too. But then I got impatient. I started writing the possible answer and waited for the OP to give more info before posting it. And then I got impatient again :)

Comment: Yeah I got the same error when I logged it. Looks like I'll need to ask for some server side changes! Thanks for the help!

Comment: NP ! (Hey, someone upvote my guesswork here, please :P)